# Weird driver sticking around

Tags: windows, drivers, sd-card

There seems to be an extra driver (E:) connected to my computer that

[image: XD]

Clicking on it would tell me to insert a disk into the drive

It seems to be an SD card and has absolutely contains and holds no data

[image: Weird thingy]

So, what is it. And why is it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer probably has an SD card reader. Just like when you have a CD/DVD drive, these show up in Computer even as storage devices. When you actually insert media into them like a disk or sd card, then it will update the capacity shown in properties and allow you to view their filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a drive created by another program. Some programs require you to create a new drive to emulate a certain external drive e.g. CD, SD card etc. This may have done that itself.

When the drive is created, the program can load ISO's and other files usually associated with this drive and then install them onto your computer as if from a real SD card or CD.

Check if you have any installed programs/apps that originate from a language containing those above symbols and if not then you don't need it. DELETE the drive asap to be safe. Its probably harmless but check for malware.

Also, check your task manager for background things running just in case the problem is there.